# Trouble editting PowerShell custom prompt function

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to use a custom Prompt function to make the PowerShell prompt more like a Linux terminal.

Code is as follows;

```bsh
function Prompt(){
    $W = Split-Path -leaf -path (Get-Location)
    $prompt = Write-Prompt "$($env:UserName)@$($env:ComputerName):" -ForegroundColor Green
    $prompt += Write-Prompt $W -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
    $prompt += Write-Prompt '>'
    return ' '
}
```

problem is adding it to my Powershell profile only gives me this >

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0NzYb.jpg

a single space. I do have posh git installed. Any assistance would be hugely appreciated,

Comment: What is `Write-Prompt`? Did you mean to `return $prompt` at the end perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a command called Write-Prompt:

I haven't played around with my prompt in a while.  It can be a little tricky to get that last character in. at any rate here are 2 options that just use different methods of writing to the host.

Method 1, Using $Host:

```
Function Prompt
{
    $W = Split-Path -Path (Get-Location).Path -Leaf
    $Host.UI.Write( "Green", $Host.UI.RawUI.BackGroundColor, "$($env:UserName)@$($env:ComputerName):" )
    $Host.UI.Write( "DarkCyan", $Host.UI.RawUI.BackGroundColor, $W )
    "> "
} # End Function Prompt
```

Method 2, using Write-Host:

```
Function Prompt
{
    $W = Split-Path -Path (Get-Location).Path -Leaf
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$($env:UserName)@$($env:ComputerName):" -NoNewline
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkCyan "$w" -NoNewline
    "> "
} # End Function Prompt
```

**Minor Addition:**

This doesn't affect the answer, but you don't necessarily have to reference the `.Path` property from `Get-Location`'s output.  Even though the output is an object and the `-Path` parameter of `Split-Path` will only accept `[String[]]`.  Since the `(Get-Location).ToString()` returns the string value of the Path property, the `-Path` parameter will cast it the same way; effectively `[String](Get-Location)`.  The code, `$W = Split-Path -Path (Get-Location) -Leaf` is a little shorter although probably a little less efficient, due to the extra casting step.

Comment: That's brilliant, thank you so much. The write-prompt function I think comes from posh git > https://github.com/dahlbyk/posh-git/wiki/Customizing-Your-PowerShell-Prompt  (not that I could get it working)

Comment: Good to know.  I've been using regular Bash git, haven't played with PoShGit yet.  Any way thanks for the feedback.